# Best way to add android standard icons in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, icons, material-design, toolbar

I'm using a Toolbar from "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar".

What is the best way to add (standard) icons into your android application?

**What i did...**

- I downloaded the icons from this website (24dp, white): https://design.google.com/icons/
- Unzipped the zip files & put each icon into the specified folder in the app (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi)
- I added the mdpi icon to the folder (Resources/Drawable)

Now I reference the the icon in layout like:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
```

But my icons are a bit blurry.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: Picture of the blury image (search icon)]

**Toolbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Searchview where I link to the icon**

```
<menu
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:orderInCategory="200"
      android:title="Zoeken"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      android:inputType="textCapCharacters"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Is it just search Icon that you want or more icons are there ?

Comment: It's more like each icon (in the future). All the icons wich I download appear to be a bit blurry so I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: add your toolbar layout code also

Comment: I added the layout code.

Comment: Normally I use 36dp  images for toolbar. Check my answer for sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I use `36dp` images as Icons in `toolbar`. You can download the 36 dp variant from the dropdown at bottom from [Material Design Icons](https://design.google.com/icons/). You can download that and replace in menu as

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
  android:id="@+id/action_search"
  android:orderInCategory="200"
  android:title="Zoeken"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_36dp"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
  app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
  android:inputType="textCapCharacters"/>
</menu>
```

Also you can add other custom Icons (36 dp icons for clarity) to your toolbar as below

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/editButton"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_edit_white_36dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: And wich file from the folders (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) should I add to the drawable folder?

Comment: You should add all the files. You should be having all the drawable forlders in you Resources folder. If not you need to create them all. And add all the files to respective folders

Comment: Don't you have all drawable folders in Resources as shown in this image ? http://imgur.com/dzPS3pz

Comment: I added all the files but I need the icon in the drawable or it isn't working...
I got these folders in my app: **drawable** - **mpimap-hdpi** - **mpimap-mdpi** - **...**

but only one drawable folder.

Comment: Expand all the folders under your Resources Folder ,showing all the files and share a screenshot so that I can have a look

Comment: Thank you! I added the drawable-folders (hdpi, mdpi, ...) and now I don't have the blurry icons!